# Django adding data to a database table with foreign key

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-forms

I have a model with a foreign key to standard Django User database.

```
models.py

class Links(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
        full_link = models.CharField('Полные ссылки пользователя', max_length=100)
        short_link = models.CharField('Короткие ссылки пользователя', max_length=100)
    
        class Meta:
            verbose_name = 'Ccылка'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Ссылки'
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.full_link
```

There is my forms.py and views.py

```
forms.py

class AddLink(forms.ModelForm):
    full_link = forms.CharField(required=True)
    short_link = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Links
        fields = ['full_link', 'short_link']

views.py

def link(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    addUserLink = AddLink(request.POST)
    if addUserLink.is_valid():
        addUserLink.user = request.user
        addUserLink.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Ссылка добавлена')
else:
    addUserLink = AddLink()
    
        return render(request, 'users/links.html', {'userLinks': userLinks, 'title':'Пользовательские ссылки', 'addUserLink': addUserLink})
```

I want to add a record to the Link table in the database. An authorized user enters values ​​in the form, and I have an error **NOT NULL constraint failed: users_links.user_id**. I think when I try to submit the form it does not send user_id. Why?

Comment: Because you haven't added it as a field on your form.

Comment: So either add it as a field in your form, or add `null = True` on your user field in your model

Comment: what type of field i must add? CharField? When i add CharField and press submit, page just refresh and doesn't send to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify the `user` field in the form. Therefore, either add `null=True` to your `user` field in your model, or add the user field to the form, as follows:

```
class AddLink(forms.ModelForm):
   
    class Meta:
        model = Links
        fields = ['full_link', 'short_link', 'user']
```

Comment: in yr example user field will show in html. i dont want to show field user in the form. If i detete 'user' from fields will it help?

Answer (score 0):

Can do it by:

```
models.py

class Links(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, blank=True)
    full_link = models.CharField('Полные ссылки пользователя', max_length=100)
    short_link = models.CharField('Короткие ссылки пользователя', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Ccылка'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ссылки'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_link

views.py

def link(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        addUserLink = AddLink(request.POST)
        print(addUserLink)
        if addUserLink.is_valid():
            instance = addUserLink.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = request.user
            instance.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Ссылка добавлена')
    else:
        addUserLink = AddLink()


forms.py

class AddLink(forms.ModelForm):
    full_link = forms.CharField(required=True)
    short_link = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Links
        fields = ['full_link', 'short_link', 'author']
```